# Font is nil when setting NSFontAttributeName

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I'm trying to change my font from medium to regular, but I keep getting nil when setting the font type for `NSFontAttributeName`. I can get the font as medium without a problem, but when I try to set it to regular programmatically, my program crashes because the font is nil.

```
let attrsUnselected = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Roboto-
Regular", size: 15)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.gray]

let attrsSelected = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", 
size: 15)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.black]
```

Before my app crashes, I can see that the font is actually set to regular.

I don't know how many different ways I get validate that the font has been imported into the project.

[image][image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following:

- The font is added to the target
- Its listed under "Copy Bundle Resources" on your target

And does it show up in the list of available fonts when you print them?